# Can Nikon PK-11a extension tubes be used with G lenses, keeping aperture control?

Tags: lens, nikon, aperture, extension-tubes

I own a D3200 and 3 G lenses (kit lenses + 35mm f1.8G) and I was wondering if I could use an extension tube PK-11a with them keeping aperture control functional. At Nikon website seems to say no, but I saw that this ring has a lever similar to the one that controls aperture in G lenses...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I personally don't see the lever you mean on any picture I found.
2. The lever might only be used to switch the aperture to a completely open state for measuring the exposure. I am not completely aware whether G lenses get the aperture set mechanically or completely electronically from the camera.
3. This link:
   http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/19709943
   says there is no transfer of aperture for G lenses with the PK-11a

Find a workaround here:
[Is there a way to adjust the aperture of a Nikon lens without a camera or physical aperture ring?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/49978/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-aperture-of-a-nikon-lens-without-a-camera-or-physic)

Comment: Thanks kamuro, I will look for other (cheap) solution to do macro...

Comment: I suspect the 'lever' Juan spotted is the fixed prong/protrusion of the 'bayonet' which is there to ensure correct alignment, rather than the sprung aperture lever.

Comment: There also is the lever that reads the aperture set on the lens from AI lenses up to D lenses. There is no transmission from the camera back to the lens, though.

Comment: Even if there were a mechanical aperture link, I'd expect you'd run into problems because the camera has no electronic contact with the lens  re. focal length, max/min aperture, etc. Basically G lenses are pretty limited when not used directly on the camera.